# pH of water after getting heated

Tags: acid-base, ph

When water is heated, the molecules of the water gain energy which leads to dissociation of water molecules. Does this means that pH of water has changed?

Comment: Yes, but not by much.

Comment: Dissociation equilibrium constants are temperature dependent. You can find tables of pKw and water neutral pH versus temperature on many places on internet. It has been supposed to be found  before asking.

Comment: http://www.iapws.org/relguide/Ionization.pdf

Comment: It's an intriguing question though. One might think that a sample of water that has equal concentrations of $\ce{H3O+}$ and $\ce{OH-}$ always has $pH = 7$. But if $pK_w \ne 14$... hmm...

Comment: The neutral pH is equal to 7 just accidentally, as pKw=13.99 for 25 Deg C. People are too fixed on this "magical" value.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic product of $\ce{H2O}$ is changing with temperature. It is $14.94$ at $0$°C, $14.17$ at $20$°C, $13.83$ at $30$°C and $12.26$ at $100$°C.

So the pH of pure water is  $7.47$ at $0$°C, $7.08$ at $20$°C, $6.92$ at $30$°C, and $6.13$ at $100$°C